# SNMPSet Execute Remote Command

Tags: snmp

I am trying to use SNMPSet to execute a command on a remote server. I'm not 100% sure this is possible. I've been researching this, but I cant find any way to do this. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think this should be possible? Please edit your question and include details of what you've tried, what isn't working, etc.

Comment: I dont know if its possible or not. I am asking if its possible or not. Given the specific words in the question, it is a very difficult question to just google. If you google "snmp remote shell command" you get tons of unrelated results. Same with "snmpset execute command". I've tried googleing for the answer, but I'm sure you can understand that it isnt a simple question to google for.

Comment: SNMP is not set up to run ad-hoc commands. If you want to do this, just use SSH.

Comment: "SNMP is not set up to run ad-hoc commands. If you want to do this, just use SSH." <---that is your answer. Also, calm down. No need to insult. Again, if you want to take issue with anything, post on meta.SF.